# *mobxAutorun makes the whole component not being rendered

Tags: angular, mobx

I must be missing something obvious. If I add `*mobxAutorun` on the top of [`tags.component.html`](https://github.com/hsharpsoftware/angular-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/app/home/tags/tags.component.html#L1), the whole component is not rendered. If I remove it, it is rendered on the bottom of the page, but the the code reflecting to the `commonStore.isLoadingTags` is not processed correctly.

I followed everything at [mobx-angular](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-angular), I event [updated one of the samples to Angular 4+](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-angular/pull/41), but my simple change in the [Realworld Angular 4+/Mobx repository](https://github.com/hsharpsoftware/angular-realworld-example-app) is still not working. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: Don't forget to import the `MobxAngularModule` so it is accessible in the module you're using the `*mobxAutorun` directive.

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [
        ...
        MobxAngularModule
    ]
})
```

I ran into the same issue today in my own code, not in the mentioned sample. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46636005/1956072) is specific for the provided sample. If anyone runs into this issue, you can generally say that the `MobxAngularModule` needs to be available in the module/component you're using `*mobxAutorun`. It does not matter if you're using some kind of `SharedModule` in which you re-export it or you just declare the import directly in the module you're using the directive.

Answer (score 0):

So as [explained](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-angular/issues/42#issuecomment-335037161) by [Adam](https://github.com/adamkleingit), it is because if `SharedModule` is used, the you need to import `MobxAngularModule` in `SharedModule`, not `AppModule`, and then export it as well so it's available throughout the app:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    MobxAngularModule
  ],
  ...
  exports: [
    ...
    MobxAngularModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```